# View list of users and groups configured for a project in Sonarqube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube, user-permissions

How to view authorized list of users and groups configured for a project in Sonarqube 6.7? (feature was there in earlier versions of Sonarqube (refer screenshots))

We have recently migrated from Sonarqube 4.5 to 6.7 and in v4.5 access for few projects were configured using template and for few it was configured directly without template. Now after migration we are facing access issue for many projects. Before applying new access template to such projects we would like to view current settings but Projects Management page list only 2 options; Restore Access and Apply Permission Template. Here we want to understand,

1. Current access configuration
2. Access configuration that Restore Access option enables

Permissions web services too is not listing any api to fetch project wise users/group configuration.

[image: project access configuration in v6.7]

[image: project access configuration in v4.5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Project homepage, go to Administration > Permissions. There you can see the groups and individual users granted permissions on the project and update those settings.

[image]